# Linux Bash Number Range echo syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I am very new at programming and playing around with Linux commands to help my understanding of commands and scripts but I the script that I am creating is giving me an echo syntax error and I am scratching my head to why its giving me the error. The entire script is suppose to ask for a number in a range, reads keyboard input, and loops until a proper number is entered. Also tells the user they were right or wrong with each guess.

I do not know if the script will run correctly and what else in the script is wrong so give me feedback and show me how to fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
loop=y
for i in $(seq 10)
echo Please pick a number between 1 and 10.
Read varnumber
echo you entered: $varnumber
if 
varnumber=3
then
echo Correct number, access granted...nothing
break
if 
varnumber <2>4
then echo Incorrect number, please try again.
loop=y
```

Comment: You should feed this to https://www.shellcheck.net/ first and fix everything it tells you.

Comment: As @BenjaminW. has stated, shellcheck.net is your friend on this one. Following that, look up some bash tutorials on how to do loops and if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were multiple syntax errors, friends asked to use the shellcheck tool. Take a look at that tool; that will help a lot in identifying syntax errors.

Back to your script, please change the `guessNumber` to any number and run this:

```
#!/bin/bash
guessNumber=3
let "maxGuess=$guessNumber + $(( ( RANDOM % 100 )  + 1 ))"
while  [ 1 ] ; do
    printf "\n\nPlease pick a number between 1 and $maxGuess: "
    read varnumber
    echo "   you entered: $varnumber"
    if [ "$varnumber" == "$guessNumber" ] ; then
        echo "   Correct number, access granted...nothing"
        break
    else
        echo "   Incorrect number, please try again."
    fi
done
```

things to know:

1. `guessNumber` => you configure what is the right guess.
2. `maxGuess` will be calculated based on your guessNumber
3. `$(( ( RANDOM % 100 )  + 1 ))` => generates a random number between 1-100. Change number after % to have larger or smaller range.
4. Using `while` loop instead of `for` loop, which will keep your game going until the right number is guessed. [Ctrl+c to break]
5. Key in `guessNumber` to get out of the loop/game.

Hope it give an idea how it works, happy learning bash scripting!!